# WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-speech-api

Here is my script that request Google Speech API.

```
        public string HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType) {
        file = @"C:\Users\Faizan Khan\AppData\LocalLow\DefaultCompany\GoogleSpeechTest\testing\testing7.060799.wav";

                Debug.Log(string.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}", file, url));
                HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                wr.ContentType = "audio/l16; rate=44100";
                wr.Method = "POST";
                wr.KeepAlive = true;
                wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
                        rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                fileStream.Close();
                rs.Close();

                WebResponse wresp = null;
                try {
                        wresp = wr.GetResponse();
                        Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);

                        string responseString =  string.Format("{0}", reader2.ReadToEnd());
                        Debug.Log("HTTP RESPONSE" +responseString);
                        return responseString;

                } catch(Exception ex) {
                        Debug.Log(string.Format("Error uploading file error: {0}", ex));
                        if(wresp != null) {
                                wresp.Close();
                                wresp = null;
                                return "Error";
                        }
                } finally {
                        wr = null;

                }

                return "empty";
        }
```

I am getting an error here

```
Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
```

during calling **HttpUploadFile** function. I have searched different forums but nothing worked for me. why I getting this error?

The error is:

```
WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ()
GoogleVoiceSpeech.HttpUploadFile (System.String url, System.String file, System.String paramName, System.String contentType) (at Assets/Scripts/GoogleVoiceSpeech.cs:173)
GoogleVoiceSpeech.OnGUI () (at Assets/Scripts/GoogleVoiceSpeech.cs:131)
```

Here is the complete class

```
public class GoogleVoiceSpeech : MonoBehaviour {

        public GUIText TextBox;

        struct ClipData
        {
                public int samples;
        }

        const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

        private int minFreq;
        private int maxFreq;

        private bool micConnected = false;

        //A handle to the attached AudioSource
        private AudioSource goAudioSource;

        public string apiKey;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
                //Check if there is at least one microphone connected
                if(Microphone.devices.Length <= 0)
                {
                        //Throw a warning message at the console if there isn't
                        Debug.LogWarning("Microphone not connected!");
                }
                else //At least one microphone is present
                {
                        //Set 'micConnected' to true
                        micConnected = true;

                        //Get the default microphone recording capabilities
                        Microphone.GetDeviceCaps(null, out minFreq, out maxFreq);

                        //According to the documentation, if minFreq and maxFreq are zero, the microphone supports any frequency...
                        if(minFreq == 0 && maxFreq == 0)
                        {
                                //...meaning 44100 Hz can be used as the recording sampling rate
                                maxFreq = 44100;
                        }

                        //Get the attached AudioSource component
                        goAudioSource = this.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                }
    }

        void OnGUI() 
        {
                //If there is a microphone
                if(micConnected)
                {
                        //If the audio from any microphone isn't being recorded
                        if(!Microphone.IsRecording(null))
                        {
                                //Case the 'Record' button gets pressed
                                if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-100, Screen.height/2-25, 200, 50), "Record"))
                                {
                                        //Start recording and store the audio captured from the microphone at the AudioClip in the AudioSource
                                        goAudioSource.clip = Microphone.Start( null, true, 7, maxFreq); //Currently set for a 7 second clip
                                }
                        }
                        else //Recording is in progress
                        {

                                //Case the 'Stop and Play' button gets pressed
                                if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-100, Screen.height/2-25, 200, 50), "Stop and Play!"))
                                {
                                        float filenameRand = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0.0f, 10.0f);

                                        string filename = "testing" + filenameRand;

                                        Microphone.End(null); //Stop the audio recording

                                        Debug.Log( "Recording Stopped");

                                        if (!filename.ToLower().EndsWith(".wav")) {
                                                filename += ".wav";
                                        }

                                        var filePath = Path.Combine("testing/", filename);
                                        filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filePath);
                                        Debug.Log("Created filepath string: " + filePath);

                                        // Make sure directory exists if user is saving to sub dir.
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
                                        SavWav.Save (filePath, goAudioSource.clip); //Save a temporary Wav File
                                        Debug.Log( "Saving @ " + filePath);
                                        string apiURL = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=" + apiKey;
                                        //string apiURL = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=" + apiKey;

                    string Response;

                                        Debug.Log( "Uploading " + filePath);
                                        Response = HttpUploadFile (apiURL, filePath, "file", "audio/wav; rate=44100");
                                        Debug.Log ("Response String: " +Response);

                                        var jsonresponse = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(Response);

                                        if (jsonresponse != null) {     
                                                string resultString = jsonresponse ["result"] [0].ToString ();
                                                var jsonResults = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse (resultString);

                                                string transcripts = jsonResults ["alternative"] [0] ["transcript"].ToString ();

                                                Debug.Log ("transcript string: " + transcripts );
                                                TextBox.text = transcripts;

                                        }
                                        //goAudioSource.Play(); //Playback the recorded audio

                                        File.Delete(filePath); //Delete the Temporary Wav file

                                }

                                GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/2-100, Screen.height/2+25, 200, 50), "Recording in progress...");
                        }
                }
                else // No microphone
                {
                        //Print a red "Microphone not connected!" message at the center of the screen
                        GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
                        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/2-100, Screen.height/2-25, 200, 50), "Microphone not connected!");
                }
        }

        public string HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType) {
        file = @"C:\Users\Faizan Khan\AppData\LocalLow\DefaultCompany\GoogleSpeechTest\testing\testing7.060799.wav";

                Debug.Log(string.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}", file, url));
                HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                wr.ContentType = "audio/l16; rate=44100";
                wr.Method = "POST";
                wr.KeepAlive = true;
                wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
                        rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                fileStream.Close();
                rs.Close();

                WebResponse wresp = null;
                try {
                        wresp = wr.GetResponse();
                        Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);

                        string responseString =  string.Format("{0}", reader2.ReadToEnd());
                        Debug.Log("HTTP RESPONSE" +responseString);
                        return responseString;

                } catch(Exception ex) {
                        Debug.Log(string.Format("Error uploading file error: {0}", ex));
                        if(wresp != null) {
                                wresp.Close();
                                wresp = null;
                                return "Error";
                        }
                } finally {
                        wr = null;

                }

                return "empty";
        }
```

Comment: what url are you using

Comment: @BugFinder i am using this url "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=WithMyKey"

Comment: @BugFinder i have also added complete class in the question.