# What is Google Speech To Text Rest APi Address?

Tags: c#, google-speech-api

I have got the **speech API ke**y as below image depicted but i am unable to find where to request? where is URL given?
[image]

1. "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key="+ apiKey;
2. "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=" + apiKey;
3. "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize?key=${" + apiKey + "}";

All are i guess wrong as **[i am getting DNS name resolution error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195968/webexception-error-nameresolutionfailure-in-unity3d)**. what is the correct URL (remember i didn't purchase the service yet), where i can find it.

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/) you can see you can query https://speech.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1 and it will return a result with a json document with all of the API endpoints.

Comment: hi scott thanks for the link but it didn't provide the full url i guess it same like this i mentioned in the question "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=" + apiKey;